# SetInterval function not setting innerHTML on top of the hour

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, setinterval, innerhtml

I’m trying to make an artificial and dynamic web radio station that has a full schedule that I choose. However, the function Check() doesn’t seem to replace the existing P tag when I run it within the SetInterval function. I’m beginning to wonder if my issue is with the if arguments...

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
marklevin = "<p><button onclick='Control()'>Pause</button><br /><div><embed type='application/x-vlc-plugin' pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org'  width='50%'  height='20%' id='vlc' loop='yes' autoplay='yes' target='http://4293.live.streamtheworld.com/MARK_LEVINAAC?&uuid=15F6FB00-0000-0001-1755-1EBAEDA617CA'></embed></div></p>";
laura = "<p><button onclick='Control()'>Pause</button><br /><div><embed type='application/x-vlc-plugin' pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org'  width='50%'  height='20%' id='vlc' loop='yes' autoplay='yes' target='http://noxsolutions.mp3.miisolutions.net/nox/laura'></embed></div></p>";
sean = "<p><button onclick='Control()'>Pause</button><br /><div><embed type='application/x-vlc-plugin' pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org'  width='50%'  height='20%' id='vlc' loop='yes' autoplay='yes' target='http://prn-hannity-ic-pri.ng.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/811/60538/v1/auth.akacast.akamaistream.net/prn_hannity_ic_pri'></embed></div></p>";
cbs = "<p><button onclick='Control()'>Pause</button><br /><div><embed type='application/x-vlc-plugin' pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org'  width='50%'  height='20%' id='vlc' loop='yes' autoplay='yes' target='http://1451.live.streamtheworld.com:3690/CBSNEWSDIALUP_SC'></embed></div></p>";
control = 0
divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
ps = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var currentdate = new Date();
hours = currentdate.getHours();
minutes = currentdate.getMinutes();
seconds = currentdate.getSeconds();
if (hours > 0 && hours < 4) {
 document.write("Laura Ingraham Show<br />Midnight to 4");
 document.write(laura);
 set2 = "laura";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours == 4) {
 document.write("Mark Levin Show<br />4 AM");
 document.write(marklevin);
 set2 = "marklevin";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours == 5) {
 document.write("CBS Radio News<br />5 AM");
 document.write(cbs);
 set2 = "cbs";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours == 6) {
 document.write("Sean Hannity show<br />6 AM");
 document.write(sean);
 set2 = "sean";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours == 7) {
 document.write("Laura Ingraham Show<br />7 AM");
 document.write(laura);
 set2 = "laura";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours == 8) {
 document.write("CBS Radio News<br />8 AM");
 document.write(cbs);
 set2 = "cbs";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours > 8 && hours < 11) {
 document.write("Sean Hannity Show<br />9 AM to 11 AM");
 document.write(sean);
 set2 = "sean";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours == 11) {
 document.write("Laura Ingraham Show<br />11 AM");
 document.write(laura);
 set2 = "laura";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours == 12) {
 document.write("Mark Levin Show<br />NOON");
 document.write(marklevin);
 set2 = "marklevin";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours > 12 && hours < 15) {
 document.write("CBS Radio News<br />1 PM to 3 PM");
 document.write(cbs);
 set2 = "cbs";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours == 15) {
 document.write("Mark Levin Show<br />3 PM");
 document.write(marklevin);
 set2 = "marklevin";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours == 16) {
 document.write("Laura Ingraham Show<br />4 PM");
 document.write(laura);
 set2 = "laura";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours == 17) {
 document.write("Sean Hannity Show<br />5 PM");
 document.write(sean);
 set2 = "sean";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours == 18) {
 document.write("Laura Ingraham Show<br />6 PM");
 document.write(laura);
 set2 = "laura";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours > 18 && hours < 21) {
 document.write("Mark Levin Show<br />7 PM to 9 PM");
 document.write(marklevin);
 set2 = "marklevin";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours == 21) {
 document.write("Laura Ingraham<br />9 PM");
 document.write(laura);
 set2 = "laura";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours == 22) {
 document.write("Sean Hannity Show<br />10 PM");
 document.write(sean);
 set2 = "sean";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
if (hours == 23) {
 document.write("Mark Levin Show<br />11 PM");
 document.write(marklevin);
 set2 = "marklevin";
 div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
 }
function Check() {
 currentdate = new Date();
 hours = currentdate.getHours();
 minutes = currentdate.getMinutes();
 seconds = currentdate.getSeconds();
 if (hours > 0 && hours < 4 && set2 != "laura") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "Laura Ingraham Show<br />Midnight to 4<br />" + laura
  set2 = "laura";
  }
 if (hours == 4 && set2 != "marklevin") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "Mark Levin Show<br />4 AM<br />" + marklevin
  set2 = "marklevin";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours == 5 && set2 != "cbs") {
  document.write("CBS Radio News<br />5 AM");
  document.write(cbs);
  set2 = "cbs";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours == 6 && set2 != "sean") {
  document.write("Sean Hannity show<br />6 AM");
  document.write(sean);
  set2 = "sean";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours == 7 && set2 != "laura") {
  document.write("Laura Ingraham Show<br />7 AM");
  document.write(laura);
  set2 = "laura";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 // Copy this code throughout the entire page. It's more stable than before.
 // ps[0].innerHTML = 
 // Instead of
 // document.write(
 if (hours == 8 && set2 != "cbs") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "CBS Radio News<br />8 AM<br />" + cbs;
  set2 = "cbs";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours > 8 && hours < 11 && set2 != "sean") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "Sean Hannity Show<br />9 AM to 11 AM<br />" + sean;
  set2 = "sean";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours == 11 && set2 != "laura") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "Laura Ingraham Show<br />11 AM<br />" + laura;
  set2 = "laura";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours == 12 && set2 != "marklevin") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "Mark Levin Show<br />NOON<br />" + marklevin;
  set2 = "marklevin";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours > 12 && hours < 15 && set2 != "cbs") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "CBS Radio News<br />1 PM to 3 PM" + cbs;
  set2 = "cbs";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours == 15 && set2 != "marklevin") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "Mark Levin Show<br />3 PM" + marklevin;
  set2 = "marklevin";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours == 16 && set2 != "laura") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "Laura Ingraham Show<br />4 PM" + laura;
  set2 = "laura";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours == 17 && set2 != "sean") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "Sean Hannity Show<br />5 PM" + sean;
  set2 = "sean";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours == 18 && set2 != "laura") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "Laura Ingraham Show<br />6 PM" + laura;
  set2 = "laura";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours > 18 && hours < 21 && set2 != "marklevin") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "Mark Levin Show<br />7 PM to 9 PM" + marklevin;
  set2 = "marklevin";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours == 21 && set2 != "laura") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "Laura Ingraham<br />9 PM" + laura;
  set2 = "laura";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours == 22 && set2 != "sean") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "Sean Hannity Show<br />10 PM" + sean;
  set2 = "sean";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
 if (hours == 23 && set2 != "marklevin") {
  ps[0].innerHTML = "Mark Levin Show<br />11 PM" + marklevin;
  set2 = "marklevin";
  div_content = divs[0].innerHTML;
  }
}
function Control() {
 just_set = 0
 if (control == 0 && just_set != 1) {
  divs[0].innerHTML="<p>Paused</p>";
  control = 1;
  just_set = 1
 }
 if (control == 1 && just_set != 1) {
  divs[0].innerHTML=div_content;
  just_set = 1;
  control = 0;
  Check()
 }
}
myVar = setInterval(Check, 1000);
window.i = 0
//alert(window.i)
function buttonFunction() {
 //alert(window.i);
 //alert(window.i);
 if (window.i > 1) {
  //alert(window.i)
  window.i = 0;
 }
 if (window.i == 0) {
  var currentdate = new Date();
  hours = currentdate.getHours();
  minutes = currentdate.getMinutes();
  seconds = currentdate.getSeconds();
  days = currentdate.getDay();
  months = currentdate.getMonth();
  years = currentdate.getFullYear();
  years_to_seconds = years * 11404800;
  months_to_seconds = months * 950400;
  days_to_seconds = days * 86400;
  hours_to_seconds = hours * 3600;
  minutes_to_seconds = minutes * 60;
  window.start_time = years_to_seconds + months_to_seconds + days_to_seconds + hours_to_seconds + minutes_to_seconds + seconds;
 }
 if (window.i == 1) {
  var currentdate = new Date();
  hours2 = currentdate.getHours();
  minutes2 = currentdate.getMinutes();
  seconds2 = currentdate.getSeconds();
  days2 = currentdate.getDay();
  months2 = currentdate.getMonth();
  years2 = currentdate.getFullYear();
  years_to_seconds2 = years2 * 11404800;
  months_to_seconds2 = months2 * 950400;
  days_to_seconds2 = days2 * 86400;
  hours_to_seconds2 = hours2 * 3600;
  minutes_to_seconds2 = minutes2 * 60;
  end_time = years_to_seconds2 + months_to_seconds + days_to_seconds2 + hours_to_seconds2 + minutes_to_seconds2 + seconds2;
  total_tim = end_time - window.start_time;
  total_time = total_tim.toString();
  alert("It's been " + total_time + " seconds since you hit the button.");
  document.cookie="timeittook=" + total_time;
 }
 window.i = window.i + 1;
}
</script>
```

Also, the page hung when I changed the reference to Check() in the setInterval command from Check() to Check, even though that is the correct syntax.

Comment: Your code is far too long. Read [ask]

Comment: When did you test the code? You use `document.write` for some output, which would overwrite the current page. Also, there is a gap between 0:00 and 1:00 where it won't do anything.

Comment: I ran it at 11 PM until about eight in the morning. And when I say that it “hung,” it like completely froze and the little beach ball was spinning.

Comment: Also, I believe all my document.write declarations were in the beginning. Without them, the p tag wouldn’t exist in the first place, unless I did it in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I have fixed it. I have multiple issues:

1. The VLC plugin was frozen. That’s why it hung.
2. My code actually did update, but I couldn’t tell because the laptop was closed and asleep.